# Windows 10 Magento 2.4 zip install on XAMPP has nowhere to agree to terms

Tags: magento

I'm trying to get Magento 2.4 running using the production ready zip and I keep getting it to this point where I believe it's ready to start the setup process, but it's waiting for me to agree to the ToS. Unfortunately there's no agree button or instructions on if there's a file I need to edit. I just did a fresh install of XAMPP with PHP 7.4 and still have the same issue, and can't find a similar mention on google.

Is there supposed to be an agree button, do I need to edit a file?[image: No agree button]

Term & Agreement link leads here, still no agree button. Getting started link takes me to installation instructions for a Linux CLI[image: Still no agree button]

I saw I may still need to run the `composer install` command even on Windows, but I was under the impression the production ready zip already had the dependencies included. Where am I going wrong??

Update: I got composer running in windows terminal and it returns that there is nothing to install.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [official site docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/composer.html), in a note at the top of the installation instructions for a CLI install of Magento 2.3:

"The Web Setup Wizard is being deprecated in Magento 2.3.6 and will be removed in Magento 2.4.0. After it is removed, you must use the command line to install or upgrade Magento."

So you cannot install Magento 2.4 without touching the command line.